# How to get a vector from the elements along a fixed dimension in a 3D array?

Tags: matlab

I have a 3D array in MATLAB like this:

```matlab
val(:,:,1) =
    1.1461    2.3993
    2.3993   15.4036

val(:,:,2) =
    1.0041    0.8106
    0.8106   10.6503

val(:,:,3) =
    1.0001    0.9895
    0.9895    3.0384

val(:,:,4) =
    1.0024    0.9936
    0.9936    2.0169
```

It's a `2 x 2 x 600` array. I want the second element of each of the 600 "matrices". Is there a simple way to extract these in MATLAB?

The output I would desire is like this:

```matlab
output = [ 2.3993; 0.8106; 0.9895; 0.9936 ];
```

My attempt so far has been the following:

```matlab
val(1, 2, :)
```

But, this returns:

```matlab
ans(:,:,1) =
    2.3993

ans(:,:,2) =
    0.8106

ans(:,:,3) =
    0.9895

ans(:,:,4) =
    0.9936
```

I need these values as a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach accessing `val(1, 2, :)` is correct. Nevertheless, the output produced has a size of `1 x 1 x 4`. What you want to do is to remove the (unnecessary) dimensions of length 1. That is what the [`squeeze`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/squeeze.html) function is for.

Having a 3-dimensional array `val` like yours and fixed indices `x`, `y` for the first and second dimensions, we just surround your command with `squeeze`:

```matlab
% 3-dimensional array
val = reshape(1:36, 3, 3, 4)

% Squeezed output for fixed x, y in dimensions 1 and 2
x = 1;
y = 2;
out3d = squeeze(val(x, y, :))
```

The output is the following:

```matlab
val =

ans(:,:,1) =
   1   4   7
   2   5   8
   3   6   9

ans(:,:,2) =
   10   13   16
   11   14   17
   12   15   18

ans(:,:,3) =
   19   22   25
   20   23   26
   21   24   27

ans(:,:,4) =
   28   31   34
   29   32   35
   30   33   36

out3d =
    4
   13
   22
   31
```

This works for arbitrary dimensions and number of indices.

A 4-dimensional array with two fixed indices will produce a 2-dimensional output:

```matlab
% 4-dimensional array
val = reshape(1:108, 3, 3, 4, 3)

% Squeezed output for fixed x, y in dimensions 1, 2
x = 1;
y = 2;
out4d = squeeze(val(x, y, :, :))
```

Output:

```matlab
val = (omitted here)

out4d =
     4    40    76
    13    49    85
    22    58    94
    31    67   103
```

A 4-dimensional array with three fixed indices will again produce a 1-dimensional output:

```matlab
% 4-dimensional array
val = reshape(1:108, 3, 3, 4, 3)

% Squeezed output for fixed x, y, z in dimensions 1, 2, 3
x = 1;
y = 2;
z = 1;
out4d = squeeze(val(x, y, z, :))
```

Output:

```matlab
val = (omitted here)

out4d =
    4
   40
   76
```

Hope that helps!